# Universal (across DEs) file indexing (desktop search) and launcher?

Tags: gnome, 13.04, software-recommendation, launcher, kde

I am running Ubuntu 13.04.

I often switch between Gnome and KDE. Each has a desktop search and launcher. In Gnome, search box on hitting Windows key is supposed to provide search results (including files with matching names, matching content, applications, etc.) and in KDE, Krunner does the same. Both DEs use their own indexing and searching applications.

Is not there a way by which this is shipped out to a third party application? That single application will search and index all the files. A global keyboard shortcut launches that application and off you go.

I had tried kupfer and it works excellently -- except that Kupfer does not index the contents of the files.

Is there any solution?

Comment: If you can make do without a launcher functionality, a dedicated desktop search engine like [Recoll](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/) might be the way to go. A [Recoll plugin](https://code.launchpad.net/~pmarchwiak/synapse-project/recoll-plugin) for [Synapse](https://launchpad.net/synapse-project) is in the works.

Answer (score 2):

Several launchers could work

### Synapse

You can try `synapse` which is an application launcher activated by a customizable hotkey. From the [synapse website](http://synapse.zeitgeist-project.com/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page)

> Synapse is a semantic launcher written in Vala that you can use to start applications as well as find and access relevant documents and files by making use of the Zeitgeist engine.

It doesn't support indexing file contents. It does, however show recent files matching your search term (through Zeitgeist).

### Launchy

http://www.launchy.net/

> Launchy is a free cross-platform utility designed to help you forget about your start menu, the icons on your desktop, and even your file manager.

Unsure whether it support indexing file contents